# React Bootstrap 3 Modal

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap4-modal

I am using the HTML theme provided by the client which uses Bootstrap 3 based modals, I converted the modals using React-Bootstrap (V 0.33.1) Modals and `react-bootstrap-modal` but turns out that both packages are using context API and I end up having a warning on the console. Can anyone suggest me anything with which I can implement the Bootstrap 3 components with minimal damage, since downgrading React won't be a good idea?